# How to use UMD in browser without any additional dependencies

Tags: javascript, html, requirejs, systemjs, commonjs

Suppose I have an UMD module like this (saved in *'js/mymodule.js'*):

```
(function (global, factory) {
  typeof exports === 'object' && typeof module !== 'undefined' ?     factory(exports) :
  typeof define === 'function' && define.amd ? define(['exports'], factory) :
  (factory((global.mymodule = global.mymodule || {})));
}(this, function (exports) { 'use strict';
    function myFunction() {
        console.log('hello world');
    }
}));
```

How can I use this module in an HTML file like this? (without requirejs, commonjs, systemjs, etc...)

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Using MyModule</title>
    <script src="js/mymodule.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<script>
/* HOW TO USE myFunction from mymodule.js ??? */
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Many thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 27):

Ok, so you are running in an environment without RequireJS, CommonJS, SystemJS, etc.

The key line is `factory((global.mymodule = global.mymodule || {}))` this does a few things:

1. If `global.mymodule` truthy, then it is equivalent to

   ```
   global.mymodule = global.mymodule // A noop.
   factory(global.mymodule)
   ```
2. Otherwise it is equivalent to:

   ```
   global.mymodule = {}
   factory(global.mymodule)
   ```

**Inside the factory**: Your factory you should export what you want to export from your module by assigning to `exports`. So you'd export `myFunction` by doing `exports.myFunction = myFunction`.

**Outside the factory**: Outside, the exported values will be on `mymodule` which was exported to the global space. When you want to use `myFunction`, for instance, you do `mymodule.myFunction(...)`.

In case that's not clear. The factory in your code is the function that starts with `function (exports) {`, where you've correctly put `myFunction`.

Comment: This is the best answer and gives a lot of information that is otherwise buried and hidden. Everyone seems to expect that you will use RequireJS, SystemJS, Webpack, etc.

Comment: I came to this page while trying to use a bundled UMD file produced with Rollup. Great question, and great answer...

Comment: I'm not familiar with UMD or whatever "factory" is (what does "inside the factory" and "outside the factory" mean?) - I'm unsure how to implement this answer. What code (either something I can copy+paste, or something I can use as a starting-point) do I need? Do I need to reimplement `function require( moduleName )` myself?

Comment: Is there a trick to get bundlers to do this? In particular, vite?

Answer (score 22):

Simple answer: if you use usual UMD, it should be available in `window['mymodule']` (or `window.mymodule`) or whatever name lib has. You can inspect `window` object in DevTools if unsure how it named.

Comment: I'm loading a UMD module into my page (by creating a `<script async="" src="">` element inside another script). After the new script is loaded (i.e. the `HTMLScriptElement.load` event fires) there isn't a `window['myScriptName']` member defined. Does this mean I'm not using a true UMD module, or is the `window['mymodule']`-thing a convention only a subset of all UMD modules use? Where do they add themselves?

Comment: @Dai maybe. What you can do, open your module code, format it with "pretty print" and look for the beginning or the end of the file, there could be `exports`, `global.` etc. Possibly your lib exported with another name or inside `commonJsStrict` object or somewhere else.

Comment: I want to give another example: include rxJS in your page `<script src="https://unpkg.com/rxjs@7.1.0/dist/bundles/rxjs.umd.min.js"></script>`. Afterwards you should be able to use rxJS, e.g., `rxjs.range(1,10).subscribe(x => console.log(x))`. Note that `rxjs.range` is the fully qualified reference to the method. This could be an import in another scenario: `import { range } from "rxjs";`. Further, note that `window['bla']` references the variable `bla` in global scope. Thus, you could also use `window['rxjs'].range`.

Comment: If you are unsure how the module is named, then you might want to open the DevTools and inspect the `window` object. When typing `window.` in the DevTools, then autocompletion should show names in the global scope. One of these names should be your module.

Answer (score 8):

In its current form, you cannot use **myFunction()** from **myModule.js** at all.
Your myModule.js is not exposing (exporting) anything at all. You will have to first add this line to myModule.js

```js
exports.myFunction = myFunction;
```

So that your module code becomes:

```js
(function(global, factory) {
  typeof exports === 'object' 
  && typeof module !== 'undefined' 
  ? factory(exports) :
    typeof define === 'function' 
    && define.amd 
    ? define(['exports'], factory) :
      (factory(
          (global.mymodule = global.mymodule || {})
        )
      );
}(this, function(exports) {
  'use strict';

  function myFunction() {
    console.log('hello world');
  }
  // expose the inner function on the module to use it
  exports.myFunction = myFunction;
}));
```

Now when you will run this code in your .html file, browser creates a global object called 'mymodule' that has this method 'myFunction'.

You can call this method in your .html file as

```js
myModule.myFunction();
```

Complete .html file will be:

```html
    <!doctype html>
    <html>
    <head>
        <title>Using MyModule</title>
        <script src="js/mymodule.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
    <script>
    /* HOW TO USE myFunction from mymodule.js ??? */
    /* Answer: */
    mymodule.myFunction();
    </script>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score -2):

Here is an example how to [render UMD React component](https://github.com/coryhouse/react-umd-example):

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <script src="https://unpkg.com/react@16.1.1/umd/react.development.js"></script>
  <script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16.1.1/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
  <script src="my-component.js"></script>
  <title>React App</title>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="root"></div>
  <script>
    ReactDOM.render(
      React.createElement(MyComponent),
      document.getElementById('root')
    );
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I downvoted this answer because the OP isn't asking about React, and React comes with its own module-helper logic.

Answer (score -4):

The amd module format is meant to be loaded asynchronously, so you cannot directly reference the file in a script tag. If this is being used for development, then you can use a loader like requirejs (see [this link](https://addyosmani.com/writing-modular-js/) on amd specifics). If what you're after is to use this in production mode, then a few alternatives are:

1) Use requirejs but run the optimisation process which will bundle up the amd file
2) Use another minification process, such as webpack or build it into your frontend tooling (grunt, gulp etc).

I'm afraid in terms of loading the file directly, this isn't possible, due to the nature of amd (ability to declare dependencies on other modules).

Hope this helps.

Comment: I am afraid you're mixing up UMD with AMD.